# ORA-00600 when Creating Materialized View

Tags: oracle, view, materialized

I'm trying to create a materialized view like using the following:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW orders_mv AS
  SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM table1
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM table2
        ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)
  WHERE rownum <= 5;
```

But it gives me an ORA-00600 and disconnects me with the usual disconnect error:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW orders_mv
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 89299
Session ID: 11416 Serial number: 40331
```

We are running Oracle 12c.   Is there some bug with creating a materialized view and using an order by clause in this fashion?

Comment: ORA-00600 errors can only be diagnosed and resolved by Oracle Support. They could indicate a bug, but there are plenty of good observations in Mathguy's answer too. My guess is the internal errors will resolve themselves if you follow his suggestions; otherwise be prepared to open a Service Request. You won't be able to get detailed help on ORA-00600 errors on this forum.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with materialized views. Did you try to run the `select` by itself, without creating a view? That would be the first step in trying to figure out what is going on.

In a query with set operations (such as `UNION`), the `order by` clause can only reference columns in the `select` list: by number, or if you listed the columns explicitly, then by name (or by alias if you used aliases).

Specifically, you can't `order by` an expression like `dbms_random.value`. You wouldn't even be allowed to order by an arithmetic expression (say, or string expression, etc.) that depends only on columns specifically named in the `select` list.

So: even if you named all the columns in the `select` list (instead of the poor practice of `select *`), you wouldn't be able to do what you tried. You would still only be allowed to order by columns in `select` - if you try to order "at the same level" as the set operation.

Instead, you will need three levels of `select`. In the most deeply nested subquery, perform the `UNION` but don't try to order. In the middle `select` statement order the result of the sub-subquery by `dbms_random.value`. And in the outer query filter by `rownum`. This will work with `select *` too (it's just a poor practice, but it is valid).

Comment: Looks like the 3 level query worked.  Appears they have X number of records in a combination of tables, but only want a random sample of 5 in the final MV.   So, appreciate the tip.   And yes, I agree, listing column names is always better than *.    Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be reproduced in Oracle XE Version 18.4.0.0.0 on Windows (note that in case of `ORA-0600`this is relevant information)

```
.... 
No more data to read from socket
```

As diagnosed in other answer this works:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW orders_mv AS
  SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE rnd, table1.* FROM table1
        UNION
        SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE rnd, table2.* FROM table2
        ORDER BY 1)
  WHERE rownum <= 5;
```